# What does "GET_ACCOUNTS" actually do?

Tags: android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS

I've been searching around Android developers guide, and it says for `GET_ACCOUNTS`

```
Allows access to the list of accounts in the Accounts Service
```

So what does `GET_ACCOUNTS` actually do? Can an app read the device's email address or phone contacts?

Comment: Search for it on this page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows you to list the system accounts in this way:

```
Type      | AccountName
Google    | bob@gmail.com
Exchange  | clare@live.com
FaceBook  | alice@yahoo.com
```

Of course you cannot get the password.